# Use both Xcode 10.2.x and Xcode 11b together with Visual Studio 2019 Mac/Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, xcode11

This is likely a time-sensitive issue (it's now 06/2019 and I expect VS2019 to be updated to support Xcode11 when it's out of beta) but I’d like to continue to use Xcode 10.2 and the associated tooling with Visual Studio 2019 for Mac while at the same time exploring some of the new features of Xcode 11b.  Running Xcode 11b causes the associated command-line tools to install, and the 10.2 simulator(s) to stop working.  Similarly, following the workaround outlined [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6216) then causes the 11b simulator to fail to launch.

Is there a way to have both Visual Studio and Xcode 11b operational at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to at least switch between them, although it’s a little bit of a brute-force approach.  There may be a lighter-touch version of the following script, and this isn’t an exercise in Bash-foo.  As usual save it somewhere (I’ll use `switchXcode.sh`, below) and make executable.

Quit any Xcode/VS2019 and run it with:

```
./switchXcode.sh [--useold|--usenew] [--old </PATH/TO/OLD/XCODE.app>] [--new <PATH/TO/NEW/XCODE.app>]
```

Where `--useold`/`--usenew` should be obvious, and `--old` and `--new` allow you to override the/my default locations for Xcode.

It takes a couple of minutes to run.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Script to swap between Xcode production and beta versions

# Ask for root privilege
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"

# Adjust to suit, or override with args
OLD_XCODE=/Applications/Xcode.app
NEW_XCODE=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app
USE=NONE

# Parse command line args

POSITIONAL=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
    --old)
        OLD_XCODE="$2"
        shift; shift
        ;;
    --new)
        NEW_XCODE="$2"
        shift; shift
        ;;
    --useold)
        USE=OLD
        shift
        ;;
    --usenew)
        USE=NEW
        shift
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown argument"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
done

# Validate inputs

[ ! -d "$OLD_XCODE" ] && echo "'old' Xcode directory '$OLD_XCODE' does not exist; exiting." && exit 1
[ ! -d "$NEW_XCODE" ] && echo "'new' Xcode directory '$NEW_XCODE' does not exist; exiting." && exit 1

# Switch to correct Xcode

case "$USE" in
  "OLD")
      echo "Switching to 'old' Xcode ($OLD_XCODE)"
      sudo xcode-select -s $NEW_XCODE/Contents/Developer/ &&\
      sudo $NEW_XCODE/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch &&\
      sudo rm -Rf /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/* &&\
      sudo xcode-select -s $OLD_XCODE/Contents/Developer/ &&\
      sudo $( for pkg in $OLD_XCODE/Contents/Resources/Packages/*.pkg; do sudo installer -pkg "$pkg" -target /; done ) &&\
      sudo $OLD_XCODE/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
      ;;
  "NEW")
      echo "Switching to 'new' Xcode ($NEW_XCODE)"
      sudo xcode-select -s $OLD_XCODE/Contents/Developer/ &&\
      sudo $OLD_XCODE/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch &&\
      sudo rm -Rf /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/* &&\
      sudo xcode-select -s $NEW_XCODE/Contents/Developer/ &&\
      sudo $( for pkg in $NEW_XCODE/Contents/Resources/Packages/*.pkg; do sudo installer -pkg "$pkg" -target /; done ) &&\
      sudo $NEW_XCODE/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
      ;;
  *)
      echo "NO XCODE SPECIFIED"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

echo "Done."
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who would want a GUI-based solution :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/ios-sdk. Refer this link to know how to set/point to the iOS SDK / the another xCode version you like to use in Visual Studio for Windows & Mac.

This can be set in Visual Studio as follows

Visual Studio
Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings

Visual Studio for Mac -> Preferences -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> iOS

[image]